# Make polygons contiguous automatically

Tags: qgis, postgis

I am running QGIS 2.14 and PostGIS 2.3 for PostgreSQL 9.5.

Is there any way, whether in QGIS or PostGIS (or somewhere else), to automatically make polygons which are not contiguous to be contiguous, let's say by meeting halfway were they do not touch ?

I didn't find any consistent source of information on the web allowing this to be done, it even seems to me that the topology validation tools cannot consider the case as being a topological error, but I must say I didn't find these tools to be really ergonomic, so if it is possible I just didn't manage to make them work properly.

To illustrate, here comes a picture showing what my problem is:

[image]

Comment: "Integrate" could be what you want: https://pro.arcgis.com/de/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/integrate.htm

Comment: @AndreasMüller Indeed it seems to be something like what I am looking for, I don't have ArcGIS, though...

Comment: ahh, oversaw this, so may be this is helpfull: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69425/seeking-open-source-alternative-to-arcgis-desktops-integrate-tool

Comment: @AndreasMüller Indeed I ended up there after your first comment. For now my first tests are not giving any satisfying results (I even wish I understood how this works ^^) Thanks though.

Comment: I have achieved this by buffering and then negative buffering by the same amount . Once the internal gaps are closed, there is no way for a negative buffering to being them back, but the external polygon extent should be unchanged

Comment: Automating the process is another matter. Could ypu add more info as to where the polygons come from, what tolerance you want to apply, etc