# Identifying zip codes that cover multiple townships

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, vector, spatial-join

I have shapefiles with zip code tabulations in Massachusetts and township areas. Some zip codes fall completely within a single township, while some zip codes cross multiple town borders. I want to identify those multi-township zip codes and shade those zip areas differently than the other zips. What I believe I should be doing is joining by location zip polygons that overlap with town polygons. However, the problem with this is that the polygon borders for matching town/zip borders don't align perfectly in the shapefiles, so that every single zip polygon technically "overlaps" every neighboring township polygon, so I can't use this to identify multi-town zips. Does anyone have any advise on the best way to proceed here?

Comment: ArcGIS has a tool called integrate which will edit data and move lines to be coincident within a distance threshold.  I see from this link there is a similar tool in GRASS which I have not tried. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69425/seeking-open-source-alternative-to-arcgis-desktops-integrate-tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do a polygon overlay between the two layers using the QGIS ***Intersection*** algorithm (available in the *Processing Toolbox*).
2. Open the resulting layer and its attribute table and

   1. Use the *field calculator* to create new fields containing the area (formula: `$area` - under Geometry) and perimeter (formula: `$perimeter` - under Geometry) of each polygon.
   2. either

      a) Select the areas that are larger than a certain size (use the minimum size you expect for a "proper" overlap).

      b) Use the *field calculator* to calculate the area / perimeter, and use that new field (and the area and perimeter fields if you like) in a select expression to get rid of typical "sliver" polygons (the ratio between area and parameter is small - very elongated polygons, and the total area is typically small).
   3. Use the QGIS ***Statistics by Categories*** algorithm (available in the *Processing Toolbox*) on the selected features (*Selected features only*), grouping (*Field(s) with categories*) on zip code - those with a value larger than `1` in the `count` column of the resulting table are "multi-township".

Comment: Thank you! This is an elegant solution to the problem.