# Seeking PostGIS equivalent of ArccGIS Desktop Integrate Tool

Tags: postgis, topology

Is there a PostGIS equivalent to the ArcGIS "Integrate" tool for (multi)polygons?

Basically it would be an extension of `ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology`, which instead of considering each feature as an independent entity, would take into account the spatial relation with its neighbouring features, and avoid the creation of slivers, inter-feature gaps, and border overlaps.

Full description can be found here:
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/integrate.htm

An idea partially taken from [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/69431/142513) to [Seeking open source alternative to ArcGIS Desktop's Integrate tool?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/69425/115) could be to use a sequence based on the following:

- `ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology`
- `ST_Snap`

but I was hoping in a more consistent tool.

**References:**

- https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology.html
- https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Snap.html

Comment: You should check out the topology extension.  You'll have to set up topology rules for your polygons.  It might help you.  https://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/Topology.html

Comment: Thanks: even if not an out-of-the-box solution, that is a useful toolbox.