# Merging layer features by boundaries

Tags: qgis, editing, boundaries

I'm trying to combine the features from a layer in QGIS by distance. Basically I have the following layer with some features.

[image: qgis with layer features]

I wanted to remove the small gaps (as seen in below image) between them.

[image: small gaps between features]

But I'm not finding a way to resolve this, I already tried the solutions from this answer -> https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/69509/205547 but it doesnt seems to work. I also tried to use the v.clean function, but that also didn't work.

Basically the layer would be filled like the bellow image if I removed the gaps by a certain distance.
[image]

Is there a way to remove those gaps by certain threshold?

---

edit 1:

So i was playing with [@Maximilien jaffrès](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/132394/maximilien-jaffr%C3%A8s) answer and got some interesting results using the Buffer. I measured a distance between two features and tried to use that distance as a parameter to "join" them.
[image: distance between features]

I got what i was looking for but the outer boundaries changed as seen below.
[image: outer boundaries changed]

In that case the "outer" boundaries should remain the same and the "inner" boundaries should get snapped.

Even though [@BERA](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/32958/bera) answer would work **perfectly**, it would take more time to achieve in cases where there be more features (usually the user import a file with 2-5 groups of multiple features).

Considering that i gave a shot at [@MrXsquared](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/107424/mrxsquared) answer and i got a good result as seen below.
[image: inner boundaries changed, outer boundaries ramained]

Some outer boundaries got changed as well, but with that i can simply merge the original with the snapped, apply a v.clean and dissolve them, the result is the below.

[image]

Comment: add a buffer to this layer ? vector => add buffer and define a distance that would be your treshold. To only close the gap , you do buffer and then reverse the buffer

Comment: If those are your only features, start editing and fix them manually. Draw a new feature covering the gaps, merge it with existing

Comment: You can also give "snap geometries to layer" a try to remove the gaps. This way you dont need to buffer on all sides and build a difference after that.

Comment: Just to speak about your edit, when you have the outer boundaries that has changed , one step you can add is to do again a buffer with the same offset but negative, you should have your boundaries back ... on a pedantic note it's a technique called erosion of polygon  (buffer + with dissolve then same buffer but minus the offset).